# How to integrate angular2-useful-swiper

Tags: angular, swiper.js

```
    ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: ReferenceError: Swiper is not defined
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
ReferenceError: Swiper is not defined
    at SwiperComponent.ngOnInit (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:20818:28)
    at DebugAppView._View_Home0.detectChangesInternal (Home.ngfactory.js:8303:84)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js:57290:15)
    at DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js:57396:45)
```

It is giving me this error after doing all process. Dont understand what happening. Also the GitHub repo in this particular has a lot of errors.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-useful-swiper

Comment: Any news? I face the same error.

Answer (score 6):

In order to achieve it, follow the following steps (explained also in [angular2-useful-swiper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-useful-swiper) documentation):

```
npm install --save angular2-useful-swiper

npm install --save swiper@3.4.2
```

then add the js and css to angular-cli.json:

```
"styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "../node_modules/swiper/dist/css/swiper.css"        
],
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/swiper/dist/js/swiper.js"                
],
```

Afterwards, import the SwiperModule at the appropriate level in your app.

For example in app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule }       from '@angular/core';

import { SwiperModule } from 'angular2-useful-swiper';

import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';
import { DemoComponent }   from './demo.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        SwiperModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        DemoComponent
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Then, insert the swiper component to the component to create a slider and add the content:

```
<my-component>
   <swiper [config]="config">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">HERE GOES SELECTOR 1</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">HERE GOES SELECTOR 2</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">HERE GOES SELECTOR 3</div>
        </div>
        <!-- Add Pagination -->
        <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    </swiper>
</my-component>
```

Set the config for the swiper in the component and bind it to the component config property as above:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

    config: SwiperOptions = {
        pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
        paginationClickable: true,
        nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
        spaceBetween: 30
    };
```

Set the height and width of the component. It can be targeted by its name, **swiper**.

```
swiper{
    height: 300px;
    width: 400px;
}
```

After following the previous steps, if you get:

> ERROR ReferenceError: Swiper is not defined

Just add manually the Swiper 3.4.2 to the single page:

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.4.2/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.4.2/js/swiper.js"></script>
```

Comment: do we still need the swiper package for latest ngx-useful-swiper?

Comment: @pranabw Just found out the angular2-useful-swiper has been deprecated and renamed to [ngx-useful-swiper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-useful-swiper). Without really using it, I would say the procedure is the same / quite similar to the one I mention in the answer. If you get a ReferenceError saying that Swiper is not defined, then yes, add manually the Swiper to the single page.

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1**

Add Swiper to your single page

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.3.1/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.3.1/js/swiper.js"></script>
```

...

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/zhHFiemhGr7KKSfpZ5H7?p=preview)**

Answer (score 1):

**Install**

```
npm install --save angular2-useful-swiper
```

**Setup**

Add Swiper to your single page

```
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.3.1/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.3.1/js/swiper.js"></script>
```

After that declare it in your **app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        // your other imports
        SwiperModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        // your declarations
        DemoComponent
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Should work now

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-useful-swiper